# По клику изменять .text div'a туда и обратно

Tags: javascript

Есть div с текстом: Показать все. По клику на него должен меняться текст на Скрыть все. И так по очереди. Подскажете?

```
$('#more').text('Скрыть все');
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('#more').on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).text() === 'Скрыть все') {
    $(this).text('Показать все')
  } else {
    $(this).text('Скрыть все')
  }
});
$('#more').text('Скрыть все');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="more"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Только для образовательных целей: реально ли это сделать через переменные, или не стоит городить городуху?

Comment: Реально и нужно делать только через переменные.

Comment: По возможности подскажете решение на этот конкретный пример?

Comment: Если для образовательных целей то я бы предложил подумать самим. Могу только сказать что нужно объявить и использовать переменные для текста,

Comment: Первый раз `Скрыть все` срабатывает только со 2 раза.

Comment: Это какой то баг в среде исполнения. Работает здесь http://jsfiddle.net/g28yuymv/130/

Comment: Я так и понял, потому что код нормальный. Удивился даже

Answer (score 3):

Кое какое решение с использованием переменных (код честно скопипащен с ответа Михаила и чутка изменен) :

```js
var text1 = 'Скрыть все';
var text2 = 'Показать все';

$('#more').on("click", function() {
  var currentText = $(this).text();
  currentText = currentText === text1 ? text2 : text1;
  $(this).text(currentText);
});
$('#more').text(text1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="more"/>
```